# Intel network contrroller *-network UNCLAIMED

Tags: drivers, wireless, debian

After installing linux on my lenovo legion Y520 i can't seem to get my wireless connection running. The icon for ethernet connection is there, but the one for wireless is missing.

After running

> lshw -C network

i get *-network UNCLAIMED for my network controller.

> ```
>  *-network UNCLAIMED       
> description: Network controller
> product: Intel Corporation
> vendor: Intel Corporation
> physical id: 0
> bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
> version: 78
> width: 64 bits
> clock: 33MHz
> capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
> configuration: latency=0
> resources: memory:a4200000-a4201fff
> ```

**EDIT:**

My wifi card is intel dual band wireless AC 3165

Comment: which wifi card do you have? Unclaimed usually means that the driver for the card isn't installed

Comment: I tried searching for them how do i install them ?

Comment: you need Linux-image-extra and linux-firmware installed.

Comment: Please edit to include results for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; rfkill list; dmesg | grep iwl` Thanks

Comment: @ravery, this should probably be an answer rather than a comment.